# TabView is creating tabs for each grandchild

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-tabview

The `TabView` is creating a `tabItem` for each sub `View` in the child. Why is this happening?

```
struct MyView : View {

  var body: some View {
    TabView {
      MyOtherView().tabItem { Text("item") }
    }
  }
}

struct MyOtherView : View {
  var body: some View {
    // 4 children in this view
    Text("blah1")
    Text("blah2")
    Text("blah3")
    Text("blah4")
  }
}
```

The `TabView` creates a tab for each **grandchild**:

[image]

The tab's contents are of the **individual** texts accordingly:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

What is going on?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SwiftUI TabView repeats first entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74655821/swiftui-tabview-repeats-first-entry)

Answer (score 1):

Add VStack in view

```
struct MyView : View {

  var body: some View {
    TabView {
      MyOtherView().tabItem { Text("item") }
    }
  }
}

struct MyOtherView : View {
  var body: some View {
    // 4 children in this view
  VStack{ //--> add VStack
      Text("blah1")
      Text("blah2")
      Text("blah3")
      Text("blah4")
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do this it will resolve.
For each view, you need to take all elements into a single stack to prevent unexpected behavior.

[SwiftUI TabView repeats first entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74655821/swiftui-tabview-repeats-first-entry/74655979#74655979)

```
VStack{
 Text("blah1")
    Text("blah2")
    Text("blah3")
    Text("blah4")
}
```

Comment: yes I did this but it doesn't seem reasonable. is this a bug in tabview?

Comment: TabView will create a new tab for everything that is directly underneath the body. In your case it is a separate tab for Text() because it is separate. Once you wrap it all in a VStack then it will only create a single tab with everything inside that VStack

Comment: why would anybody want this behavior?